# How create an app like Facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall, facebook-fbml

I need to develop an app like http://www.facebook.com/pampers?v=app_151853638190293
It's a facebook wall, i'm  using php.

Answer (score 1):

In facebook fan page you have to use FBML and FBJS for creating any kind of application..Ordinary JS wont support on that page. U can create it easily by downloading Facebook API and by having a look into the following url,

[FBML + FBJS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

If you have any other clarification i am ready to explain you clearly.. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Other question will be if I can build an app that it works into my site and in an app facebook. In both side should has the look UI Facebook. I don't want to develop two apps, one for website and other for app facebook..